# @RequestPayload not binding soap input param to java class

Tags: java, spring-boot, soap

I am developing SOAP service from wsdl. I am using @RequestPayload annotation to map my request input. But it is returning the parameters as null.
When I try to unmarshall the xml separately, it gives me the parameters.
Any pointers why it is returning null? Where can I debug where this unmarshalling happens in spring?

Comment: Please share your code and error that you are facing